# How to create windows app which can read pen drive data in react Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, window

I am trying to develop an windows application using **React Native** which can read pen drive data. I tried `React-Native-File-System`, But seems like React-Native-File-System library doesn't work with windows application.

Here's my code:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

export default function App() {
  const [downloadsFolder, setDownloadsFolder] = useState('');
  const [documentsFolder, setDocumentsFolder] = useState('');
  const [externalDirectory, setExternalDirectory] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    //get user's file paths from react-native-fs
    setDownloadsFolder(RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath);
    setDocumentsFolder(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath); //alternative to MainBundleDirectory.
    setExternalDirectory(RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Text> Downloads Folder: {downloadsFolder}</Text>
      <Text>Documents folder: {documentsFolder}</Text>
      <Text>External storage: {externalDirectory}</Text>
    </>
  );
}
```

It is throwing this error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'RNFSFileTypeRegular')
```